# Serialize derived classes with boost

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, polymorphism

I have three classes defined as:

```
class Base
{
public:
    int myvar1;
    int myvar2;
    ...
};

class Base2 : Base
{
public:
    Base2(...) : Base(...)
    {
    }
};

template<typename T> class Derived
{
public:
    Derived(...) : Base2(...)
    {
    }
};
```

I need to serialize the base class including also the derived classes with boost to send it via sockets. How can i do it?

***EDIT 1***

```
std::auto_ptr<Base2>(new Derived(...))
```

Comment: You have a pointer to the base or an object of the derived class? Are you using ASIO or what part of boost?

Comment: I'm not using boost asio but my own network class. I have an object of the Base2 class inside an std::auto_ptr. I've edited my answer with some more details

Comment: Are you using boost::serialization?

Comment: sure but I don't understand how I can use it to serialize the derived and the base classes. Basically Derived class has N params, Base2 is only a wrapper that should be casted to Base and sent via sockets...

Comment: Though I cannot show detailed explanation since I have not used Boost
serialization deeply, referring the following links may help probably.
As for serialization of derived classes through base pointer,
[here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#derivedpointers)
is the document.
As you mentioned the use of your own network class, this may not help
directly, but you will be able to find some hints
[here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html#boost_asio.examples.serialization).

Comment: so I can now serialize the Base class from Base2 but i still cannot understand how to serialize Derived class :( It seems that the serialize function inside it is never called

Comment: @IseWisteria thank you for the link many years later it helped me a lot :)